# Reverse Proxy with https redirect in Lighttpd

Tags: reverse-proxy, https, lighttpd

I've got a django application here that uses a lighttpd reverse proxy.  We recently moved it behind an elastic load balancer on EC2 and I'm having trouble working out the correct config to do what I want.

In my example, I've got the Elastic Loadbalancer setup with a certificate and accepting 80/443 requests on behalf of a single instance which lighttpd listens on 80 and does reverse proxy to the app running in apache on port 9900.  The ELB does a health check on the instance by the public dns (ec2-blah-blah.amazonaws.com) on port 80 and users are accessing it at app.example.com.

I need to provide:

1. redirect to https for all requests via http made to any host except EC2 public DNS.
2. reverse proxy to 127.0.0.1 port 9900 for all requests made via https
3. reverse proxy to 127.0.0.1 port 9900 for requests via http to EC2 public DNS only.

Can someone help?

Comment: I was able to handle this via the suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414799/access-x-forwarded-proto-in-lighttpd-configiuration